# Windows Firewall Does Not Block VMs From Accessing Port 135 on Windows 10 Host

Tags: windows, networking, security, firewall, vmware

I have a newly setup Windows 10 device with VMWare installed, and the guest OSes will be designated malware analysis playgrounds with (limited) network access. However, I cannot get the Windows firewall to block imbound access from guest OSes to port 135/445 on the host Windows 10 device. Are there any workarounds, or is it possible to apply any of the following settings?

1. Treat all VMs as external devices on a LAN. (E.g. enforce the firewall imbound rules against the "host-only" network.)
2. Disable port access from a certain IP range. (E.g. deny all access from the IPs dispatched by the "host-only" network DHCP.)
3. Block guest to host port access via VMWare settings.

Also, the following items are out of my control and I cannot change any of them.

1. Install Linux. (The device isn't mine and is managed by my employers.)
2. Install 3rd-party utilities. (Unless they're from well-established service providers/open source projects that I can convince my employers to give green lights to.)

Example of impacket rpcdump output run in a guest OS after applying the inbound firewall rule blocking TCP port 135/445 on the host:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: On which network interface are these VMs?

Comment: @harrymc The guests are usually on a host-only network. But occasionally we may have to attach them to a bridged network (virtual) interface to intercept real-world C2 traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was me being an idiot.

Should anyone run into similar problems by accident, **make sure you have disconnected the default NAT virtual adapter from the guest.** The reason being is that the NAT adapter exposes the host's network interfaces to the VM and renders the firewall rules useless. The VM would be accessing the host *directly* if the NAT virtual adapter is present therefore bypassing the firewall!